# Make button disappear after hitting my route

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, mongodb

I want my user to press a button to "attend" then show a "thank you" and remove the button.

Here's my button:

```
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
      <form action="/events/<%= event._id%>/guests" method="POST" novalidate class="needs-validation">
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto mb-2">
              <button id="attendingBtn" onclick="buttonDisappear()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">I'm attending</button>
            </div>
          </form>        
        </div>
```

When I use `remove()` in my function (below) the button disappears after it's clicked but doesn't hit the route or send data to my db:

```
function buttonDisappear() {
    document.getElementById("attendingBtn").remove();
}
```

But when I use `style.display = none;` the button disappears until the page reloads and the button is back.

```
function buttonDisappear() {
    document.getElementById("attendingBtn").style.display = 'none';
}
```

This is because I have a res.redirect back to the page in my function (below).

```
module.exports.addGuest = async (req, res) => {
    const event = await Event.findById(req.params.id);
    const guest = new Guest(req.body.guest);
    event.guests.push(guest);
    await guest.save();
    await event.save();
    res.redirect(`/events/${event._id}`);
}
```

How do I get the button to POST data *then* have the card show a "thank you" or just have the button go away?

Comment: You can possibly have a `onsubmit` on the form with the code from the `onclick` (and remove the `onclick`).

Comment: hey @prasad_ thanks for the comment and I like the thinking but I just tried it and button briefly disappears until the page reloads, then it's back.

Answer (score 1):

1. When you click on button - store identifier of customer in the cookie/localStorage
2. When load the page - check if there is the cookie, if present - hide button
3. Use Promises - addGuest should return Promise and in your buttonDisappear function resolve it:

```
addGuest(someArgs).then(() => {
   // save cookies
   // show card
});
```

Comment: Thanks this makes sense conceptually but have been trying to execute for the last couple hours without any luck.. it's a little over my head for my experience level.